# the meaning of & operator in Rust is as in c++ ? doesn't it just mean "address of"?

Tags: rust

```
fn main() {

    //! First question
    // C++: string* ptr1 = new string("hello");
    // so ptr1 contains the address of string "hello" that is allocated on heap
    let ptr1 = String::from("Hello");
    // output: 0x66c96ff910
    println!("{:p}", &ptr1);

    // C++: ptr2 = ptr1
    // so they should have now the same address
    let ptr2 = ptr1;
    // output: 0x66c96ff910
    println!("{:p}", &ptr2);

    // why ptr1 and ptr2 have different value ? (address of string on heap)
    // Isn't it because they are fat pointers?

    // Second question

    let reference1 = String::from("Hello");
    // output: 0x44fc6ff5f0
    println!("{:p}", &reference1);

    // C++: reference1 and referenc2 should point to the same address
    let reference2 = &reference1;
    // output: 0x44fc6ff650
    println!("{:p}", &reference2);

    // why reference1 and reference2 don't have the same address?
}
```

why ptr1 and ptr2 have different value ? (address of string on heap)

why reference1 and reference2 don't have the same address?

Comment: `ptr1` does not contain a pointer, despite its name, and is not equivalent to the commented C++ code you have there. In fact, it's a closer equivalent to the C++ code `auto x = std::string("hello")`, which is better code anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question I recommend to check the [books section on `String`s](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-01-what-is-ownership.html#the-string-type) again which has some great diagrams of what's actually happening:

> In this example, we would say that s1 was moved into s2. So what actually happens is shown in Figure 4-4.
>
> [image]

Applied to your code we would say that `ptr1` is moved to `ptr2`, a new memory location where we store all the data that `ptr1` has too.

---

The second part is even more obvious especially as we look at the types.

```rust
let reference1: String = String::new();
// since references type is `String` `&reference1` is of type `&String`
let reference2: &String = &reference1;
// and since `reference2`'s type is `&String`, `&reference2` is `&&String`
```

As you can see `&reference2` is a reference to a reference of the original String `reference1` while `&reference1` is just a reference to `reference1`, 1 less layer of indirection.

Comment: thank you very much, so they have different addresse because they are fat pointers ? "reference2 = &reference1" means that their member 'ptr' share the same address (contains value of string), but fat pointers themselves are different. if it is, can i access the 'ptr' member somehow ?

Comment: @Yang this has nothing to do with their being fat pointers. They have different addresses because they are different variables, just like `let x = 42; let y = &x; println!("{:p} {:p}", &x, &y);` will give you different addresses.

Comment: @Yang note that the equivalent C++ code would be: `string ptr1 ("hello"); string* ptr2 = &ptr1; printf ("%p %p\n", &ptr1, &ptr2);` which will also print two different values.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, String is definitely not a pointer, so “ptr1” and “ptr2” names are confusing. Secondly, a reference is not a pointer, but is an `usize` that contains an address at run-time. Thirdly, you’re moving `ptr1` to `ptr2` because of Rust’s move and copy semantics. Reassigning a variable’s value to another just copies or moves original value, not creates an alias. Fourthly, if you wanna get a pointer to `String`’s or `&str`’s data, you need `as_ptr` method.

```rust
let string = String::from("Hello");
let ptr1 = string.as_ptr();
let ptr2 = string.as_ptr();
```

You think of Rust in terms of C++ and don’t really wanna learn it. It’s a wrong way.

Comment: thank you very much, so the real value that ptr1 contains is a instance of "struct string" that has a pointer (member of struct) that contains the address of string on the heap, according to this ptr2 = ptr1 copy the value of the instance, and since they are two different variables they have different address, thus &ptr1 != &ptr2 ? thankyou